# Weird highlight behavior: Can't match pythonBuiltin

Tags: syntax-highlighting

python builtin function like print, len, sum...
i can match and highlight other function and its argument. but with builtin function i can't change color.

my setup:

```
syn keyword pythonStatement def nextgroup=pythonFunction skipwhite
syn match pythonFunction "\%(\%(def\s\|@\)\s*\)\@<=\h\%(\w\|\.\)*" contained nextgroup=pythonVars
syn region pythonVars start="(" skip=+\(".*"\|'.*'\)+ end=")" contained contains=pythonParameters transparent keepend
syn match pythonParameters "[^,]*" contained contains=pythonParam skipwhite
syn match pythonParam "[^,]*" contained contains=pythonExtraOperator,pythonLambdaExpr,pythonBuiltinObj,pythonBuiltinType,pythonConstant,pythonString,pythonNumber,pythonBrackets,pythonSelf,pythonComment skipwhite
syn match pythonBrackets "{[(|)]}" contained skipwhite
```

and links all to Function but the result:
[image]

EDIT 1: @Rich: for more clear, below is the expectation:
[image]

Comment: I'm afraid I can't figure out what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Rich: thanks for your reply, please refer to my EDIT 1.

Comment: Got it. What's the output of the command: `for id in synstack(line("."), col(".")) | echo synIDattr(id, "name") | endfor` when run with the cursor on `shouldBeGreen` and when the cursor is on `itsGreen`?

Comment: @Rich: super, i got result, with shouldBeGreen has no output. With itsGreen output is: `pythonFunctionCallVars  pythonFunctionCallParameters  pythonFunctionCallParam` that's actually same as pythonVars, pythonParameters and pythonParam.

Comment: then why those match don't apply on print function?

Comment: If I'm reading the above right, it looks like your `pythonVars` region can only follow a `pythonFunction` match, and `print` isn't an instance of `pythonFunction`, it's `pythonBuiltin`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66756/discussion-between-tuyen-pham-and-rich).

Answer (score 1):

I've found the issue, basically keywords can't be contained in other matches, pythonBuiltin is keyword.
:help syn-containedin, it has quote:
`Don't forget that keywords never contain another item, thus adding them to "containedin" won't work.`

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27682324/set-item-to-higher-highlight-priority-on-vim/43183947) for more discussion.

Comment: This is incorrect. The documentation you've quoted states that keywords cannot ***contain*** another item, not that they cannot be ***contained in*** other items. `containedin` is not used anywhere in your code: you do have some uses of `contains` but these are all in `match` and `region` items, which is perfectly legal.

Comment: Yes, it should be priority, people should refer to the link.